# Using an inverse value of an injective function

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to prove this lemma:

```
lemma 
  assumes "x = inv f y" and "inj f" and "x ≠ undefined"
  shows "y ∈ range f"
  using assms try
```

But Nitpick tells me this statement is not true:

```
Trying "solve_direct", "quickcheck", "try0", "sledgehammer", and "nitpick"... 
Nitpick found a counterexample for card 'b = 3
and card 'a = 2:

  Free variables:
    f = (λx. _)(a1 := b1, a2 := b2)
    x = a2
    y = b3
```

Nitpick's counterexample assumes that `y = b3` is not in the range of `f`. But in that case, how can there be an `x = inv f b3` which is not undefined?

Comment: Additionally to peq's answer you might find this blog entry [https://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/732-Isabelle_functions__Always_total%2C_sometimes_undefined] useful. It goes even deeper into how Isabelle/HOL handles totality, termination etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value `undefined` is an arbitrary unknown value. You cannot use it do check that the result of a function is not defined. All functions in Isabelle are total.

If `y` is not in the range of `f`, then `inv f y` could be any value.

You could work around this by defining your own inverse function that uses an option type.

Answer (score 3):

[peq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/303637/peq) has already provided a good answer. However, I would like to make several side remarks that you may find helpful (i.e. this is not an answer, but an addendum to peq's answer).

Generally, I am aware of two in-built convenience facilities in Isabelle/HOL for mimicking (technically, `f::'a=>'b` will always be a total function with the domain `UNIV::'a set`) functions with a restricted domain/codomain:

- Tools in the theory `Map` that are accessible from the theory `Main`. These tools could supplement peq's suggestion for working with the type constructor `option`.
- Tools in `HOL-Library.FuncSet`. These tools were developed around the idea of using `undefined` to "restrict" the domain/range of a function.

Following the second suggestion of using `HOL-Library.FuncSet`, for example, you could "restrict" `inv` to the range of the function. In this case, the theorem that you have stated can be proven under the restricted inverse:

```
theory Scratch
  imports 
    Main
    "HOL-Library.FuncSet"
begin

abbreviation inv' where "inv' f ≡ restrict (inv f) (range f)"

lemma 
  assumes "x = inv' f y" and "inj f" and "x ≠ undefined"
  shows "y ∈ range f"
  using assms unfolding restrict_def by meson

end
```

Note, however, that the theorem above is still not very useful as it implicitly omits the possibility that `undefined = inv' f y` when `y` is in the range of `f`.

---

Having tried both sets of tools that I mentioned above quite extensively, my personal opinion (not that you should assume that it carries any weight) is that often the simplest and the most natural solution is not to use them and merely provide additional assumptions that specify that the set (or particular values) upon which the function or its inverse must act are in the (desired) domain/range of the function.

Comment: Thanks! The question came up because I wanted to prove a theorem along the lines `P (inv f y) = Q y`. In informal mathematics, when assuming `P (inv f y)` for the left-to-right direction, I’d conclude there’d be a unique `x` with `f x = y`, because f injective and otherwise I couldn’t have `P (inv f y)`. Is that wrong?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, in 'informal mathematics' you merely need to provide sufficient information to convince the reader that your arguments can be formalized in some (presupposed) formal system. Nonetheless, even in informal mathematics, it is common to provide definitions of a function, its inverse and the application of a function to a value. The answer as to whether the statement `P (inv f y)` implies that there is a unique `x` with `f x = y` (provided that f is injective) depends on how the aforementioned concepts are defined.

Comment: In Isabelle/HOL, normally, you would need to state that `y` is in the range of `f` before the application of the inverse, e.g. `“y ∈ range f ⟹ (P (inv f y) = Q)”`. This is because, given how `inv` is defined (see the theory `Hilbert_Choice`), it is not possible to tell which value `inv f y` will take unless `y` is in the range of `f`. Nonetheless, you have other options at your disposal to express the idea that you are trying to express, but most such options would involve augmentation of the definitional framework (at least, by providing an alternative definition of the inverse).