# How to prove the existence of inverse functions in Isabelle/HOL?

Tags: isabelle, isar

I am trying to prove the following basic theorem about the existence of the inverse function of a bijective function (to learn theorem-proving with Isabelle/HOL):

> For any set S and its identity map 1_S, α:S→T is bijective iff there
> exists a map β: T→S such that βα=1_S and αβ=1_S.

Below is what I have so far after some attempts to define relevant things including [functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67092973) and [their inverses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67103678). But I am pretty stuck and couldn't make much progress due to my lack of understanding of Isabelle and/or Isar.

```
theory Test
  imports  Main 
    "HOL.Relation"
begin

    lemma bij_iff_ex_identity : "bij_betw f A B ⟷ (∃ g. g∘f = restrict id B ∧ f∘g = restrict id A)" 
      unfolding bij_betw_def inj_on_def restrict_def iffI 
    proof
      let ?g = "restrict (λ y. (if f x = y then x else undefined)) B"
      assume "(∀x∈A. ∀y∈A. f x = f y ⟶ x = y)"
      have "?g∘f = restrict id B"
      proof
      (* cannot prove this *)

end
```

In above, I try to give an explicit existential witness (i.e. the inverse function `g` of the original function `f`). I have several issues about the proof.

1. whether the concepts are defined right (functions, inverse functions etc.) in Isabelle terms.
2. how to expand the relevant definitions and then simplify them with function applications. I have followed some Isabelle (2021) examples/tutorials about both the apply-style simp, and structured style Isar proof but couldn't use the Isar proof fluently. Once I started the proof command, I don't know how to simp or move any further.
3. Isar has the new way of `assumes ... shows ...` for stating the theorem. Is there similar support for proving iff's (`⟷`) like the example above? Without it, there is no access to `assms` etc., and is it necessary to `assume` everything except the conclusion during the proof.

Can someone help explain how the above existential proof about inverse function can be accomplished?

Comment: It would be good to add the theory header when posting your example. In this case, it is not obvious that `HOL-Library.FuncSet` needs to be imported to get `restrict`.

Comment: @DominiqueUnruh Thanks. I just added the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the insightful remarks provided by Dominique Unruh. However, I would like to mention that a theorem that captures the idea underlying the theorem that you are trying to prove already exists in the source code of the main library of Isabelle/HOL. In fact, it exists in at least two different formats: let me name them the traditional Isabelle/HOL format and the canonical `FuncSet` format. For the former one, see the theorem `bij_betw_iff_bijections`:

```
"bij_betw f A B ⟷ (∃g. (∀x ∈ A. f x ∈ B ∧ g(f x) = x) ∧ (∀y ∈ B. g y ∈ A ∧ f(g y) = y))"
```

The situation is a little bit more complicated with `FuncSet`. There does not seem to exist a single theorem that captures the idea. However, together, the theorems `bij_betwI`, `bij_betw_imp_funcset` and `inv_into_funcset` are nearly equivalent to the theorem that you are trying to state. Let me provide a sketch of how one could express this theorem in a manner that would be considered reasonably canonical in the `FuncSet` sense (try to prove it yourself):

```
lemma bij_betw_iff:
  shows "bij_betw f A B ⟷
    (
      ∃g.
        (∀x. x∈A ⟶ g (f x) = x) ∧
        (∀y. y∈B ⟶ f (g y) = y) ∧
        f ∈ A → B ∧
        g ∈ B → A
    )"
sorry
```

---

I would also like to repeat the advice given by Dominique Unruh and provide several side remarks:

> My recommendation: Try the proof with bij instead of bij_betw first.

Indeed, this is a very good idea. In general, by trying to restrict the problem to explicitly defined sets `A` and `B`, instead of working directly with types, you touched upon a topic that is known as *relativization* in logic. For a mild layman's introduction see, for example, https://leanprover.github.io/logic_and_proof/first_order_logic.html [1], for a slightly more thorough introduction in the context of set theory see [2, chapter 12]. As you have probably noticed by now, it is not that easy to relativize theorems in Isabelle/HOL and requires additional proof effort.
However, there exists an extension of Isabelle/HOL that allows for the automation of the process of the relativization of theorems. For more information about this extension see the article *From Types to Sets by Local Type Definition in Higher-Order Logic* by Ondřej Kunčar and Andrei Popescu [3]. There also exists a large scale application example of the framework [4]. Independently, I am working on making this extension more user-friendly and very slowly approaching the final stages in my efforts: see https://gitlab.com/user9716869/tts_extension. Thus, in principle, if you know how to use Types-To-Sets and you accept its axioms, then it is sufficient to prove the theorem with `bij`, e.g.,

`"bij f ⟷ (∃g. (∀x. g (f x) = x) ∧ (∀y. f (g y) = y))"`,

Then, the theorems like
`bij_betw_iff_bijections` and `bij_betw_iff` can be synthesized automatically for free upon a click of a button (almost...).

---

Finally, for completeness, let me offer my own advice with regard to your queries (although, as I mentioned, I agree with everything stated by Dominique Unruh)

> how to expand the relevant definitions and then simplify them with
> function applications. I have followed some Isabelle (2021)
> examples/tutorials about both the apply-style simp, and structured
> style Isar proof but couldn't use the Isar proof fluently. Once I
> started the proof command, I don't know how to simp or move any
> further.

I believe that the best way to learn what you are trying to learn is by following through the exercises in the book *Concrete Semantics* by Tobias Nipkow and Gerwin Klein [5]. Additionally, I would also look through *A Proof Assistant for Higher-Order Logic* by Tobias Nipkow et al [6](it is slightly outdated, but I found it to be useful specifically for learning `apply`-style scripting/direct rule application). By the way, I have mostly self-taught myself Isabelle from these books without any prior experience in formal methods.

> Isar has the new way of assumes ... shows ... for stating the theorem.
> Is there similar support for proving iff's (⟷) like the example above?
> Without it, there is no access to assms etc., and is it necessary to
> assume everything except the conclusion during the proof.

I will make the advice given by Dominique Unruh more explicit: use `rule iffI` or `intro iffI` for this.

**Edit.** When you use `rule iffI` (or similar) to start your structured Isar proof, you need to state your assumptions explicitly for every subgoal (using the `assume ... show ...` paradigm). However, there is a tool that can generate such boilerplate Isar code automatically. It is called *Sketch-and-Explore* and you can find it in the directory `HOL/ex` of the main library of Isabelle/HOL. In this case, all you need to do is to type `sketch(rule iffI)` and the `assume`/`show` paradigm will be generated automatically for every subgoal.

**References**

1. Avigad J, Lewis RY, and van Doorn F. Logic and Proof.
2. Jech T. Set theory. 3rd ed. Heidelberg: Springer; 2006. (Pure and applied mathematics, a series of monographs and textbooks).
3. Kunčar O, Popescu A. From Types to Sets by Local Type Definition in Higher-Order Logic. Journal of Automated Reasoning. 2019;62(2):237–60.
4. Immler F, Zhan B. Smooth Manifolds and Types to Sets for Linear Algebra in Isabelle/HOL. In: 8th ACM SIGPLAN International Conference on Certified Programs and Proofs. New York: ACM; 2019. p. 65–77. (CPP 2019).
5. Nipkow T, Klein G. Concrete Semantics with Isabelle/HOL. Heidelberg: Springer-Verlag; 2017. (http://concrete-semantics.org/)
6. Nipkow T, Paulson LC, Wenzel M. A Proof Assistant for Higher-Order Logic. Heidelberg: Springer-Verlag; 2017.

Comment: @tinlyx Thank you for accepting my remarks as an answer to your question. However, I believe that in this situation it would be more appropriate to accept Dominique Unruh's answer. Not only the answer provided by Dominique Unruh came before my answer, but it also addresses your question(s) in a more direct manner. I merely provided a few side remarks that were too long for comments and tried to fill in a few gaps that remained. Of course, it is entirely up to you to choose the answer that you like the most, but your decision made me feel slightly uncomfortable.

Answer (score 3):

> `lemma bij_iff_ex_identity : "bij_betw f A B ⟷ (∃ g. g∘f = restrict id B ∧ f∘g = restrict id A)"`

I think this is not exactly what you want an I am doubtful that it is true. `g∘f = restrict id B` does not mean that `g∘f` and `id` are equal on `B`. It means that the total function `g∘f` (and there are only total functions in HOL) equals the total function `restrict id B`. The latter returns `id x` on `x∈B` and `undefined` otherwise. So to make this equality true, `g` needs to output `undefined` whenever the input of `f` is not in `B`. But how would `g` know that!

If you want to use `restrict`, you could write `restrict (g∘f) B = restrict id B`. But personally, I would rather go for the simpler `(∀x∈B. (g∘f) x = x)`.

So the corrected theorem would be:

`lemma bij_iff_ex_identity : "bij_betw f A B ⟷ (∃ g. (∀x∈A. (g∘f) x = x) ∧ (∀y∈B. (f∘g) y = y))"`

(Which is still wrong, by the way, as quickcheck tells me in Isabelle/jEdit, see the output window. If `A` has one element and `B` is empty, `f` cannot be a bijection. So the theorem you are attempting is actually mathematically not true. I will not attempt to fix it, but just answer the remaining lines.

> `unfolding bij_betw_def inj_on_def restrict_def iffI`

The `iffI` here has no effect. Unfolding can only apply theorems of the form `A = B` (unconditional rewriting rules). `iffI` is not of that form. (Use `thm iffI` to see.)

> `proof`

Personally, I don't use the bare form `proof` but always `proof -` or `proof (some method)`. Because `proof` just applies some default method (in this case, equivalent to `(rule iffI)`, so I think it's better to make it explicit. `proof -` just starts the proof without applying an extra method.

> `let ?g = "restrict (λ y. (if f x = y then x else undefined)) B"`

You have an unbound variable `x` here. (Note the background color in the IDE.) That is most likely not what you want. Formally, it is allowed, but `x` will be treated as if it was some arbitrary constant.

Generally, I don't think there is any way to define `g` in a simple way (i.e., only with quantifiers and function applications and if-then-else). I think the only way to define an inverse (even if you know it exists), is to use the `THE` operator, because you need to say something like `g y` is "the" `x` such that `f x = y`. (And then later in the proof you will run into a proof obligation that it indeed exists and that it is unique.) See the definition of `inv_into` in `Hilbert_Choice.thy` (except it uses `SOME` not `THE`). Maybe for starters, try to do the proof just using the existing `inv_into` constant.

> `assume "(∀x∈A. ∀y∈A. f x = f y ⟶ x = y)"`

All `assume` commands must have assumptions exactly as the are in the proof goal. You can test whether you wrote it right by just temporarily writing the command `show A for A` (that's an unprovable goal that would, however, finish the proof, so it tricks Isabelle into checking if it would). If this command does not give an error, you got the `assume`s right. In your cases, you didn't, it should be `(∀x∈A. ∀y∈A. f x = f y ⟶ x = y) ∧ f ' A = B`. (' is the backtick symbol here. Markup doesn't let me write it.)

My recommendation: Try the proof with `bij` instead of `bij_betw` first. (One direction is in BNF_Fixpoint_Base.o_bij if you want to cheat.)
Once done, you can try to generalize.