# Is it possible to define inverse function in Isabelle/HOL deterministically only when it exists?

Tags: isabelle

I was wondering why in Isabelle/HOL (2021), the inverse of a function is defined using the non-deterministic `SOME`:

```
definition inv_into :: "'a set ⇒ ('a ⇒ 'b) ⇒ ('b ⇒ 'a)" where
"inv_into A f = (λx. SOME y. y ∈ A ∧ f y = x)"
```

which means that the inverse of a function `f` (i.e. `inv_into (range f) f`) can be nondeterministic, (i.e. have `undefined` values).

So in ordinary math, `inv_into (range f) f` isn't really a function.

Would it be better to define the inverse operator to return a function somehow using `THE` along the lines of:

```
definition inv1_into :: "'a set ⇒ ('a ⇒ 'b) ⇒ ('b ⇒ 'a)" where
"inv1_into A f = (λx. THE y. y ∈ A ∧ f y = x)"
```

so that the inverse `inv_into (range f) f` is a function without `undefined` values if `f` is injective, and otherwise the inverse does not exist or is undefined?

I am still trying to understand the `undefined/SOME/THE` mechanism here. In ordinary math, if a function is not injective, its inverse does not exist.

Is there a mechanism in Isabelle to express the above concept. For example, can we write a "conditional definition" that's only defined when certain conditions hold (e.g. `inj f`)?

```
definition inv2_into :: "'a set ⇒ ('a ⇒ 'b) ⇒ ('b ⇒ 'a)" where
"inv2_into A f = if inj_on A f then (λx. THE y. y ∈ A ∧ f y = x) else undefined"
```

Related:

[Using an inverse value of an injective function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60913033)

Comment: In my view, one of the statements in your question is controversial: "In ordinary math, if a function is not injective, its inverse does not exist." Generally, you need to provide a reference before making such claims. It is not uncommon to define an inverse of a function as the converse of the underlying relation. In this case, the inverse of a function will not be a function, but still a well-defined relation (e.g. see *Introduction to Axiomatic Set Theory* by G. Takeuti and W. M. Zaring among many other sources where it is done this way).

Comment: @user9716869 Sure. I am not an expert here as you are. But I will try. I was reading Jacobson, Basic Algebra I, pp8, which says a map "\alpha:S -> T is bijective  if and only if there exists a map \beta: T -> S such that \beta \alpha = 1_S and \alpha \beta = 1_T" ... "We shall now ... call this the inverse of the (bijective) map \alpha". I think my college calculus book said the same many years ago.

Comment: By the way, trying to prove this basic fact in Isabelle is what motivated the question here (how do you express that the inverse exists vs not) and the other one you helped to answer.

Comment: Sure, I merely wanted to point out that there are different ways to define an inverse of a function and it is important to cite your sources, instead of generalizing the information stated in a single source. Different authors use different conventions and definitional frameworks.

Comment: I just had a thought about both of your questions. It is difficult for me to judge how much you know about type theory. However, just in case, I ought to mention that type theories provide a view of the foundations that is fundamentally different from the one provided by set theories. If you have not studied type theory, then you should do so. Of course, if you have not studied logic and axiomatic set theory, then you should do so too.

Comment: Lastly, with regard to your comments, I should mention that in Isabelle/HOL the conventional way to state that `f` a bijection between `A` and `B` is by using the predicate `bij_betw`: `bij_betw f A B`. Of course, technically, this can only be interpreted as "the restriction of `f` to `A` is a bijection between `A` and `B`".

Comment: @user9716869  Thanks a lot for your suggestions! I don't know much about type theory. Heard about some of the concepts with Coq. I will try to read more. I've posted what I have so far for proving the inverse function as a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67131207 . Hopefully, it will not be closed for asking too many questions in one post.

Answer (score 1):

[Joachim Breitner's blog article](https://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/732-Isabelle_functions__Always_total%2C_sometimes_undefined) was already mentioned in a comment to your other question, and it is indeed a very useful resource to understand what `undefined` and `SOME x. False` etc. are.

Defining an inverse operation with `THE` instead of `SOME` is of course possible, but there is no real reason to do so. The two functions only differ in that when there is no unique preimage of a value `y` w.r.t. the function `f`, the version with `THE` is completely unspecified on `y` whereas the one with `SOME` at least gives you *some* `x` such that `f x = y` (even if the choice is not unique). You basically lose nothing by using the more general version with `SOME`.

The ‘conditional definition’ you mentioned is of course also possible, but again, it has no real practical advantage over the definition of `inv_into`. Imagine you have a non-injective function and just want to get *some* value in the preimage, you don't care which one. Then you can't use your `inv2_into` function and have to define a new one after all, and re-prove all the things you proved about `inv_into`. On the other hand, the existing `inv_into` works in all situations.

I think that most people who regularly use HOL-based systems agree that returning a reasonable value, or at the very least a reasonable dummy value (e.g. 0 for functions that return a number) is usually better than leaving things unspecified or even returning `undefined`. There are situations where you have no other choice than to return `undefined` (e.g. `hd []`), but I would not artificially introduce an explicit `undefined` when it is not needed.

Comment: It could be that the name `undefined` is also adding some confusion. Because if `f x = undefined`, `f` is not actually undefined at `x`, it is defined to return the value called `undefined`. Maybe a better name (at least one that avoids the confusion) would be to call that value something like `unspecified_default_value`. Then it becomes clearer that there are no partial functions. (I'm not suggesting to actually rename it in Isabelle/HOL, just as a thought experiment for understanding.)